Is there any example for using IMU sensor broadcaster in ros2_control controller manager
I would like to ask if some one can success to use imu_sensor_broadcaster in ros2 control humble.What I have tried is following the document in here. However, it's not working. The joint_trajectory_controller is working fine. And also when I used gazebo plugin instead, I can get the IMU information.
<gazebo reference="imu_link">
        <gravity>true</gravity>
        <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <update_rate>1000</update_rate>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
            <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
                <topicName>trunk_imu</topicName>
                <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
                <updateRateHZ>1000.0</updateRateHZ>
                <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
                <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
                <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
                <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
                <initialOrientationAsReference>false</initialOrientationAsReference>
            </plugin>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

this is my urdf file for ros2_control xacro
<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>
        
        <joint name="first_joint">
            ...
        </joint>     

        <joint name="second_joint">
            ...
        </joint>     

        <sensor name="imu_sensor">
            <param name="frame_id">imu_link</param>
        </sensor> 

    </ros2_control>

Here is my .yaml
# Controller Manager configuration
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000  # Hz
    use_sim_time: true  # If running in simulation

    # Define the available controllers
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    imu_sensor_broadcaster:
      type: imu_sensor_broadcaster/ImuSensorBroadcaster

    position_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController


# Define the properties of each controller
position_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - first_joint
      - second_joint

    command_interfaces:
      - effort

    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    state_publish_rate: 50.0  # Hz
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0  # Hz

    allow_partial_joints_goal: false
    open_loop_control: true
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01
      goal_time: 0.0

 
imu_sensor_broadcaster:
   ros__parameters:

      sensor_name: "imu_sensor"
      frame_id: imu_link

Here is my launch file for start the controller
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit, OnProcessStart
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

# this is the function launch  system will look for


def generate_launch_description():

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster",
                   "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )
    
    imu_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["imu_sensor_broadcaster",
                   "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    robot_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["position_trajectory_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # create and return launch description object
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            
            RegisterEventHandler(
                event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                  target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
                  on_exit=[robot_controller_spawner],
                )
            ),
            imu_broadcaster_spawner
        ]
    )

